# custom date pipe using moment not working in ie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have added a custom pipe
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'customdatepipe'
})
export class CustomdatepipePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, format: string = ""): string {
    var momentDate = moment(value); // If moment didn't understand the value, return it unformatted.
    if (!momentDate.isValid()) return value; // Otherwise, return the date formatted as requested.
    return momentDate.format(format);
  }
}
```

When the date is in unix format it works fine but when it is in a format similar to 22-06-2020 03:15:23/(dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss)

It gives Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "2020-10-01 13:25:27" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe' even when i format the string in to timestamp it gives the same error.

I tried adding momentDate = moment(new Date(value).gettime());

Answer (score 0):

That happens cause momentJs just accept some specified formats when creating date, if you really need to create a moment from the specified `DateFormat` you should use moment as follow:

```
let dateString = '22-06-2014 22:30:40'
let dateFormat = 'dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss'
let myMoment = moment(dateString, dateFormat)
```

Text taken from [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

With specific regard to Moment's internationalization locale files:

We may choose to not accept corrections to locale strings or localized date formats, especially if they have been argued successfully for their present form.
You must make a new compelling argument for locale changes with significant, non-anecdotal evidence to support your position.
If the string or format you are asking to change is reflected in the CLDR, then you must submit a change there first and have it accepted.